# Error in custom sublime build for knitr markdown

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-build

I'm trying to create my own `sublime-build` in Sublime Text 3, since the default build in `knitr` package (https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/knitr) doesn't work (for me). I modified the one in `knitr` package as follows:

```
{
    "selector": "text.html.markdown.knitr",
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "cmd": ["Rscript", "-e", "library(knitr); knit('$file')" ],
    "shell": true
}
```

but get the error:

```
Error: '\G' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'C:\G"
Execution halted
[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['Rscript', '-e', "library(knitr); knit('C:\\GitHub\\Projects\\test\\testLaTeXing\\knitrRmd\\testRmd.Rmd')"]]
```

obviously some windows path escape issue, but how can I fix this, when I want to acces file path dynamically?

I'm working on windows7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I finally cooked up, thanks to @MattDMo.

```
{
    "selector": "text.html.markdown.knitr",
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "cmd": [ "Rscript -e \"library(knitr); knit('$file', output='$file_path/$file_base_name.md')\"" ],
    "shell": true,

    "windows":
    {
        "selector": "text.html.markdown.knitr",
        // "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
        // "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
        "cmd": ["Rscript", "-e", "library(knitr); knit('${file/\\\\/\\/\/g}', output='${file_path/\\\\/\\/\/g}/$file_base_name.md' )" ],
        "shell": true
    }
}
```

where the default command is from the knitr sublime package (https://github.com/andrewheiss/SublimeKnitr/blob/master/knitr-Markdown.sublime-build)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your `"cmd"` line to this:

```
"cmd": ["Rscript", "-e", "library(knitr); knit('${file/\\\\/\//}')" ],
```

Basically, it's a regular expression to match two `\` characters and replace them with one `/` character. Each `\` and `/` needs to be escaped by a `\`, hence the chicken scratch.

I'm not on Windows to test, but theoretically this should work. If it doesn't, another option to try is

```
"cmd": ["Rscript", "-e", "library(knitr); knit('${file/\\\\/\\/}')" ],
```

where it's replacing the `\\` with a single `\`.

Please let me know how it works, I'm interested to know!

Comment: doesn't quite work, first option removes both backslashes (after C:, rest remains), second erases "library(...) completely

Comment: oops, missed a final `/`. How about `${file/\\\\/\//}` or `${file/\\\\/\\/}`?

Comment: @adibender - see my edit and comment above - does the new version work?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work either, same problem as before. I played around a little bit and this `${file/\\\\/\/g}` replaces all double backslashes with empty string, but I can't get replacement to work..

Comment: ok, this seems to work: `"cmd": ["Rscript", "-e", "library(knitr); knit('${file/\\\\/\\/\/g}')" ],`